# INSERT query failing in cassandra with .sql file

Tags: import, cassandra, insert, export, razorsql

I have a query in Cassandra

```
SELECT * FROM "A"."B" WHERE ("systemId" = 'CZ3741X5K8');
```

It has 4 fields one VARCHAR (systemId is a VARCHAR field) and 4 blob fields.

I have exported the results of the select query into a INSERT .sql file using RazorSQL and it is successful,
However If I try to import the same file into another host, it does not import the data into the table.

```
script.sql:2:SyntaxException: line 1:257 mismatched character '0' expecting '-'
```

The source server and target server both have same Cassandra and CQL versions i.e.

```
 [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

Is there a way to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to export your data to a CSV file, you can easily import it into Cassandra using the [DataStax Bulk Loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html) (DSBulk) tool.

It is [freely available for open-source Apache Cassandra](https://www.datastax.com/blog/introducing-datastax-bulk-loader) users. Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [DSBulk Intro + Loading data](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading)
- Blog - [More DSBulk Loading examples](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading)
- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Docs - [Loading data examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkLoad.html)
- Answered questions - [DataStax Community](https://community.datastax.com/topics/dsbulk.html)

Cheers!